# I want to take all the information from SQLite DB

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, storyboard, tableview

I'm trying to get all information from `SQLite` file in `Xamarin Forms` for `iOS` and put it in a `Label` in a single `cell` in `TableView`. I'm trying the following things:

```
public partial class ErrorCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public ErrorCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

   internal void UpdateCell(Error error)
   {
        errorDescription.Text = error.Description;
    }       
}

 class TableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    List<Error> errors;

    public TableSource(List<Error> errors)
    {
        this.errors = errors; 
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = (ErrorCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell("cell_Id", indexPath);
        var errorid = errors[indexPath.Row];
        cell.UpdateCell(errorid);
        return cell;
    }
    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return errors.Count;
    }
}
```

When I try to call the method from the database that gets all items

```
 public class ErrorDataBase
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

    public ErrorDataBase(string dbPath)
    {
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        database.CreateTableAsync<Error>().Wait();
    }

    public Task<List<Error>> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        return database.Table<Error>().ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

In here:

```
 public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    static ErrorDataBase database;
    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }
    List<Error> errors;
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        errors = new List<Error>
        {
            new Error()
            {
                Description="hufhdsuhufds"
            }
            ,
            new Error()
            {

                Description="Robot died and now we have to go and buy another robot"
            }
            ,
            new Error()
            {
                Description="Dead Robot revived!"
            }
        };

        errorListView.Source = new TableSource(errors);
        //errorListView.Source = await Database.GetItemsAsync();
        errorListView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
        errorListView.EstimatedRowHeight = 90f;
        errorListView.ReloadData();
    }
    public static ErrorDataBase Database
    {
        get
        {
            if (database == null)
            {
                database = new ErrorDataBase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "SQLiteDB.db"));
            }
            return database;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
 errorListView.Source = await Database.GetItemsAsync();
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot convert from SystemCollectionsGeneric.List to
>   UITableViewSource

I really can't solve it with my development experience, can someone help me please?

Comment: Where is the class Error?  You have an extra "s" From : List<Errors>  To : List<Error>

Comment: I don't have a solution yet, I just edited the error which jdweng said..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I want to get the data from a `table` I have to create the `table` first, and I was trying to do that with full `database`, just to extract the data, but I haven't find a solution that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `List` to `UITableViewSource` , the type is mismatch.

Modify as

```
var list =  await Database.GetItemsAsync();
errorListView.Source = new TableSource(list);
```